# Setting Progressbar Color while Visual Styles are enabled

Tags: winapi

Is it possible to set background color [PBM_SETBKCOLOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760840%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and Bar color [PBM_SETBARCOLOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760838%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of a progressbar without disabling the [Visual Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ?

Answer (score 0):

No. Visual Styles must be disabled on the progress bar in order for those messages to work, as the documentation says.